# Executing Powershell SMO against a cluster with elevated privileges to update service accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering, powershell

I'm working on a Powershell script to update service accounts on named SQL instances in a failover cluster.  I'm trying to use the SMO and WMI to update this so that I can update the service account on the active node and have it populated to the other passive nodes (as would happen if I updated manually in the configuration tools).  I'm getting hung up on trying to execute the script on my local machine but updating a remote server. The error I see appears to be security related based on my Google searches and is successful if I run the script locally on the remote machine with elevated permissions (as administrator).

The code:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | Out-Null
$mc=New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer "SQLHOST01"

$srvcs= $mc.Services | Where {$_.name -like "*INSTANCE01*"} | Where {$_.Type -like "Sql*"}

$srvcs | ft name,servicestate,serviceaccount

foreach ($s in $srvcs){
    $s.SetServiceAccount("FOO\Bar","strongpass")
}
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "SetServiceAccount" with "2" argument(s): "Set service account failed. "
At line:11 char:5
+     $s.SetServiceAccount("FOO\Bar","strongpass")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

Using:
Windows 2008 R2 (remote)
SQL 2008 R2 (remote)
Windows 7 with SQL 2012 sqlps module (local)

Update:  The account I am executing the script under has administrator rights on the remote machine.

The primary question here is how can I make my call from the client machine act as if it were running under elevated permissions on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, looks like its an SMO bug (1st link) (however I have not tried the CredSSP stuff from the second link below)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/265ee700-182d-4a99-96f8-cada117fd3d3

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

Please let me know if that works..

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes in your powershell script.  I beat my head against this for an hour before i switched that out, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: jmacnett... Big thanks.